# Markup Validation Service Warnings

Tags: html, validation, encoding, w3c

I was wondering if there is a quick fix for validating website via Markup Validation Service.

I am trying to validate [this website](http://dugmanut.net/).

The website is validated as HTML5 but I am getting 2 warning which I don't have a clue how to fix them (I am using notepad++)

This are the warnings that I get from the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

1. Warning Byte-Order Mark found in UTF-8 File.

   > The Unicode Byte-Order Mark (BOM) in UTF-8 encoded files is known to cause problems for some text editors and older browsers. You may want to consider avoiding its use until it is better supported.
2. Using experimental feature: HTML5 Conformance Checker.

   > The validator checked your document with an experimental feature: HTML5 Conformance Checker. This feature has been made available for your convenience, but be aware that it may be unreliable, or not perfectly up to date with the latest development of some cutting-edge technologies. If you find any issues with this feature, please report them. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Byte-Order Mark found in UTF-8 File" validation warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554445/how-to-fix-byte-order-mark-found-in-utf-8-file-validation-warning)

Comment: As I said I am using Notepad++ and there is no "Advanced Save Options..." in notepad++ I would like to know how do do it with Notepad++ or with any other 3rd party application. Thanks!