# How to solve Android Studio after Generate signed apk error : Error:(449) Error: Found byte-order-mark in the middle of a file [ByteOrderMark]

Tags: apk, signed

I try to Generate signed apk

but error

Error:(449) Error: Found byte-order-mark in the middle of a file [ByteOrderMark]

how to solve?

I refer to link

[Android Studio writing BOM's to UTF-8 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151830/android-studio-writing-boms-to-utf-8-file)

[How to fix "Byte-Order Mark found in UTF-8 File" validation warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554445/how-to-fix-byte-order-mark-found-in-utf-8-file-validation-warning)

but I cant solve problem.

becuz I dont understand

plz your comment

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have a space between `android:name=` and `" "` and change

`<uses-permission android:name= "android.permission.x" />`

to

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.x" />`